# Find fractions of a number with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm bad with regex and could need help to identify the fractions of a number. (Is fraction the right word? I mean the numbers behind the `.` like the `.5` in `2.5`)

So if I input `10.0/5.5/41.1` into a decent `preg_replace()` (PHP) I want it to find (and replace) the `.0`, `.4` and `.1`. There is always a `.` as limiter for fractional numbers. Is this possible with regex?

Comment: You want to replace `10.0/5.5/41.1` to `10/5/41` or what ?

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear. Actually I want to use it for styling. The `.0`, `.5` and `.1` are less important and should be displayed in a smaller font to make the numbers better readable but still give the full information for those who want the exact numbers. Thats why I want to replace the `.0` with say `<span class="foo">.0</span>`

Comment: Why are you think that you need pregs?

Comment: [*facepalm*](http://picardfacepalm.com) You don't need a regex for this. Would you use a regex to add two numbers? No. (Please, dear gods, say "no".) So, why would you use a regex for this?

Comment: @JackManey Ow yeaaaaaah. Let's use [regex](http://en.ricbit.com/2013/04/arithmetic-with-regexps.html) !

Comment: @HamZa - LOL. Well, why not go all the way and break out [SimplePHPEasyPlus](https://github.com/Herzult/SimplePHPEasyPlus)?

Comment: @HamZa - I'm in the middle of teaching myself C++, and your link gave me evil thoughts about creating a wrapper class that overloads the arithmetic operators via regexes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following pattern: `(\d+)(\.\d+)` and replace with `$1<span class="foo">$2</span>`

**PHP Code**

```
$string = '10.0/5.5/41.1';
$output = preg_replace('#(\d+)(\.\d+)#', '$1<span class="foo">$2</span>', $string);
var_dump($output);
```

**Output**

```
string '10<span class="foo">.0</span>/5<span class="foo">.5</span>/41<span class="foo">.1</span>' (length=88)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d+)` : match one or more digits and put in group 1
- `(\.\d+)` : match a dot and one or more digits and put in group 2
- The replacement is quite basic, we invoke the groups by using `$n`

[**Online regex demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dK2lB7)

Comment: '0' -- will not match. Are any int number.

Comment: @sectus `There is always a . as limiter for fractional numbers` Otherwise we could simply add a `?` so it becomes `(\d+)(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)(\.\d+)/', '${1}replace_here', '10.23')
?>
```

it will print

```
10replace_here
```

To match the . you use \. because . is a wildcard used to match anything when you are talking about regular expressions.
To match one or more numbers you use \d+ (the + is at least one). So basically, the pattern is saying that I will match the left part of the . and the rignt part (including the .). You can see it inside the parenthesis. You can call what was matched using the $n where n is the position. So you will have two matches. $1 will give you the left side of the . and $2 will give the right side.

I used ${1} because maybe you want to replace the . with a number which could cause an error since $11 is a match (it match 100 times giving you $0, $1, $2, ..., $99)